# What's the term for a widely accepted cultural idea?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example sentence: Racism was a ____ in the Elizabethan Era.

I'm looking for a word/phrase that works with "breaking". I was considering "social norms" but it doesn't really mean what I want it to convey.

Even if it doesn't work with "breaking", I'd be happy to hear your suggestions anyway!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64293/discussion-on-question-by-mik-blom-whats-the-term-for-a-widely-accepted-cultura).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not fully applicable, but **zeitgeist** should get a nod:

> zeitgeist (*noun, often capitalized*) |   zeit·geist \ˈtsīt-ˌgīst, ˈzīt-\
>
> The general intellectual, moral, and cultural climate of an era

**Example:**

*The Zeitgeist of the Elizabethan Era included an acceptance of racism.*

**Sources:**

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist
2. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zeitgeist

Comment: Wish I'd seen this before submitting my speech. It's a nice word regardless. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "widely accepted worldview"

> A comprehensive world view or worldview is the fundamental cognitive orientation of an individual or society encompassing the entirety of the individual's or society's knowledge and point of view. A world view can include natural philosophy; fundamental, existential, and normative postulates; or themes, values, emotions, and ethics.[1] The term is a calque of the German word Weltanschauung [ˈvɛlt.ʔanˌʃaʊ.ʊŋ], composed of Welt ('world') and Anschauung ('view' or 'outlook').[2] The German word is also used in English.

(From Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

In your example above, assuming you want to say that racism started to appear in the Elizabethan era, in itself very debatable, then 'emergent idea' would fit;

'Racism was an emergent idea in the Elizabethan era.'

Maybe you are trying to say that racism was first acknowledged as a thing in these time?

In which case 'Racism, as a concept, ....'

You might want to raise another question as to whether 'era' gets a capital 'E' in this usage ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not really what I wanted to say. I'm not talking about the beginning of racism; I'm just saying that it was accepted at the time

Comment: then 'breaking' doesn't really fit. 'became normative' perhaps? Are you trying to say it was accepted then but not before (unlikely) or just that it was unchallenged?

Comment: The idea is that it's difficult to challenge - "...is easier than breaking ___"

Answer (score 0):

How about **norm**?

M-W:

> [**norm**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/norm): A principle of right action binding upon the members of a group and serving to guide, control, or regulate proper and acceptable
>   behavior

Your example:

> Racism was a **norm** in the Elizabethan Era.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64293/discussion-on-question-by-mik-blom-whats-the-term-for-a-widely-accepted-cultura

Comment: @michael.hor257k I don't know how to do chat.

Comment: I didn't suggest you do.

Answer (score 0):

ascendant: "moving upward" M-W

Racism was ascendant in the Elizabethan Era.